# How do I get this menu animation code to work after doing a jQuery upgrade?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

1. I read/coded a tutorial which utilized jQuery Animations for a drop-down list.
2. The tut was relatively old (I now see), but it worked!
3. That is, it worked **ONLY** using the version of jQuery *that was out when it was written* (1.4.2) and below.
4. From jQuery version 1.4.4 *and up*: **EPIC FAIL!!!**  The menus are displayed, but the drop down animations aren't working.
5. I've read what I could on the jQuery site and I simply **dont see** what has changed.
6. But then again, **I'm green**. Could be staring me in the face :-}
7. I need some illumination as to ***why*** this fails on upgrade.

The **working** fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pkdsleeper/ybwmW/

The ***"suspect"*** fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pkdsleeper/4msLH/

thanks in advance!
sleeper

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more clear about the difference between them?  It took me a minute to figure it out :)  When you said "epic fail" I was expecting it to blow up or the menu not to work - I wasn't expecting the menu to just not animate/fade in.

Comment: Yup. Mouseover the drop-downs. They work on fiddle 1 (i.e. slideIn and fadeOut) and fail on fiddle 2 (suspect).

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham Cool. Much better title!

Comment: @sleeper, did you see the answer I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is you turned off effects in your fiddle.  Just re-enabling them doesn't solve the problem, but you'll have to do that to get this to work.

So first comment out this line:

```
// $.fx.off = true;
```

Next, the code is now no longer ignoring the CSS for `#nav li ul`.

If you change the CSS to this, it will solve the problem:

```
#nav li ul 
{
    /*display:none; --- Get rid of this! */
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

This is safe because these are already set (via jQuery) in your initial definition for your `site` object.

Here's the final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4msLH/40/

Comment: Bravo! That'll work! Thank You! Can you tell me **how** you arrived at this fix? Was it something different in jQuery or defective in the original css design.

Comment: @sleeper: I opened the chrome script/elements debugger tools, inspected the element, and looked at the changes while messing with the animations.  I found that the CSS for the `UL` was marked as `display: none`.  I tried mucking about with changing from using the `css` function to `hide()`, but that didn't work.  I tried removing it, and strangly *it was still hidden*.  I then noticed the CSS came from "fiddle.jshell.net", which meant it was coming from the base CSS in the upper-right pane.  So I looked through it - low and behold, it was set manually in the base CSS script.

Comment: Before that I also looked through the change log for 1.4.whatever (the first version it was broken in, via my experimentation), and didn't find much interesting.  There was a link to 40-odd bug fixes, but the link to the bug tracker was broken.

Comment: **How** you figured it out is cooler than the answer! Wish I could give you **another** point :-} ... _of course you know, I will be using this technique from now on_ :-} Thanks for the details!